# Yielding in IteratorAggregates with Foreach in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, generator, yield

I have a class in PHP with a private array field, and implement IteratorAggregate by walking over this array and yielding new values.

```
class Item implements IteratorAggregate{
    private static $items = array(
        'a' => array(1, 2);
        'b' => array(3, 4);
        'c' => array(5, 6);
    );

    public function getIterator() {
        return array_walk(Item::$items, function ($value, $key) {
            yield array('letter' => $key, 'number' => $value[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

I then try to pass a new instance of this class to a `foreach` clause:

```
foreach((new Item()) as $value){
     process($value);
}
```

However, this fails miserably:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Objects
>   returned by Item::getIterator() must be traversable or
>   implement interface Iterator'

However, from my understanding, my class is traversable because it implements IteratorAggregate.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? I could rewrite this to turn the yield into an array, but that doesn't explain why I'm getting the error that I'm getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the `yield` applies to the closure, not to the method. This means that the closure passed to `array_walk` is a generator, `getIterator` is now just a normal method that returns the return value of `array_walk` (which is an array).

Simply use `foreach` instead of `array_walk`:

```
class Item implements IteratorAggregate{
    private static $items = array(
        'a' => array(1, 2),
        'b' => array(3, 4),
        'c' => array(5, 6),
    );

    public function getIterator() {
        foreach (self::$items as $key => $value) {
            yield array('letter' => $key, 'number' => $value[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps useful side note: `yield $key => $value[0];` is valid syntax, too.